# Website not redirecting with .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm a newbie at webdevelopment and I'm trying to redirect my website from http://www.webpage.com to http://www.webpage.com/wp/  but I can't seem to get my .htaccess file to work correctly.  I've been trying to figure this out for several days without any luck and am starting to get frustrated.   Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:nIwYzr 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webpage.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.webpage.com$ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.webpage.com/wp [R=301,L] 
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE nIwYzr:REDIRECTID

# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working 
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: First off, are you sure that your htaccess file is even read in the first place? Not all servers use it so try making a typo in it and see if you get a server error

Comment: What is your server setup?

Comment: I'm using 000webhost.com to start.  The cpanel has a widget to do redirects and it creates/updates the .htaccess file so I assume it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to move the default page across, you can use:

```
Redirect /mainpage http://webpage.com/wp/
```

where mainpage is the default page your website opens to, often something like index.html is the main page for your website. You can try this to see if your htaccess is being read at all by trying this and seeing if you can redirect individual pages.

Otherwise, your version looks like it should be correct.

As was commented above, make sure that your access file is being read. Make sure you have it in the lowest level of your domain, at `/.htaccess` and make sure your server is configures to use it.

If you are using apache, have you added:
`Options +FollowSymLinks` before this somewhere? I believe apache requires this directive if you are using rewrite, but only apache.

Making your file:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:nIwYzr 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webpage.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.webpage.com$ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.webpage.com/wp [R=301,L] 
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE nIwYzr:REDIRECTID

# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend assuming a specific file name and extension for the "root" file

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't assuming that it would be index.html, just using it as a place holder, that's why I included a comment on that below it, but you are right, I could make that more clear.

Comment: How do I tell what the main page is?  When I got to the /wp/ address it doesn't have an index.html or default.html etc.

Comment: I meant the main page for the old domain, but if /wp doesn't have one then what is it redirecting to? Also, did you try adding 'Options +FollowSymLinks'? I have used 000webhost in the past, and I can tell you some functions are blocked by them, for example getting data from other websites. I had to switch from them because I could not used public APIs for other websites because of this, but I don't know if they allow redirection.